# Arch strange error message from locale

Tags: arch-linux, locale

I have a system running Arch, which seems to be OK, except I often get messages like `man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct`

When I run `locale` I get the following

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Everything looks OK, and `LC_CTYPE` etc are set

---

`locale-gen` seems to have made no difference and `locale -a` produces the following:-

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
```

---

Obviously `locale -a` did not include my locale, even though `/etc/locale.gen` looked OK and `locale-gen` had been run.
I deleted `LANG` and rerun, it is now OK.

Comment: What does `locale -a` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to run `locale-gen` command to create missing directories.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale

Comment: I needed to kill `LANG` but ultimately this helped me fix the issue.